# Error occurs when trying to allow multiple values in a parameter to select all when running the report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have a parameter in my SSRS report which is a simple list of text values. What I want to do is to allow the person running the report to do so and show the whole report, then allow them to filter once run using the parameter.

I have selected the query as the parameter value and this works fine, the issue comes when ticking 'allow multiple values'. When I try to run the report with this box ticked, I get an error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: how do you handle your multi values parameter in your dataset query?

Comment: and if you click 'Details >>' what error does it show?

Comment: I fixed it, I wasn't using IN in my query, i was using =